# error on response.body in json service class

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i got error on data, map and item . can someone explain why I got these error.

```
  List<UserModel> userFromJson(String jsonString) {
    final data = json.decode(jsonString) as String;
     return List<UserModel>.from(data
     .map((item)=>UserModel.fromJson(item));
```

and full coding to fix it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are decoding the json data as string, while you should decode it to be a <Map<String, dynamic>>, then you map it to create List

Try

```
final data= json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

Copy my function here, you can call parseResponse anywhere you want, and then use it to create your list of objects.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> parseResponse(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [];
  parsed.map((e) => list.add(e)).toList();
  return list;
}
```

Use case

```
Future<List<UserModel>> userFromJson() async {
    Response response = await http.post(); // your http method
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = parseResponse(response.body);
    return list.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

Comment: still error and cant solve

Comment: I have added my example, try using that

Comment: only error at list = parseResponse(response.body);. is there any dependencies needed?

Comment: ya, i put top of the userFromJsom method

Comment: yeah, sorry, i've made a mistake there. check my answer again.

Comment: hmm error in 'parsed.map((e) => list.add(e)).toList();' . at .map and (e)

Comment: during compile or during runtime error?